# How to get data out of a database where the saved date is greater than another date + 1 week

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna get all my articles out of my database where the date of the last update is greater than the publishing date + 1 week.

Do you habe an idea how that should work?
In my table there is the `publish_date` and the `update_date`. Both of them contain a datetime in the following format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

It should be something like the following (which does not work!)

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE update_date > publish_date+1week
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE update_date > DATE_ADD(publish_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

See [MySQL DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain your structure (i.e. not use a DATE_ADD function), I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE update_date > publish_date + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD()` function to add weeks to DateTime in Sql Server. `DATEADD()` functions first parameter value can be week or wk or ww, all will return the same result.

`SELECT GETDATE() 'Today',  DATEADD(week,1,GETDATE())'Today + 1 Week'`